# AppFuse + wicket: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, wicket, appfuse

I have a small application written in AppFuse (multi-modular project). I want to try to use the Apache Wicket to make some kind of UI. Since AppFuse is based on Spring I found a [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/wicket-spring-integration-example/) for using Spring and Wicket together. I setted up the Wicket project using quickstart from the [Wicket page](http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html).
Whenever I try to run the Wicket app I get this error (full stack trace is at the end of the post):

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'personClubDao': 
Injection of resource dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

Here is my AppFuse project structure

```
Hello (pom)
+--core (jar) - generated by AppFuse
   +--org.microapp.hello.model
   +--org.microapp.hello.dao
+--web (war)- generated by Appfuse
   +--org.microapp.hello.service
+--wicket (war)- Wicket application
   +--org.microapp.hello
```

There are four entities in the core module - **Person**, **Club**, **House** and **PersonClub**. DAOs for Person, Club and House are registered in core/src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml (as shown [here](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Using+Hibernate)) and DAO for PersonClub entity is in org.microapp.hello.dao.PersonClubDaoHibernate.java.

Here is **PersonClubDao** interface:

```java
public interface PersonClubDao extends GenericDao<PersonClub, Long> {
    //some methods
}
```

And here is **PersonClubDaoHibernate** class:

```java
@Repository("personClubDao")
public class PersonClubDaoHibernate extends
    GenericDaoHibernate<PersonClub, Long> implements PersonClubDao {

    public PersonClubDaoHibernate() {
        super(PersonClub.class);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    //some methods
}
```

What I'm trying to do now, is to autowire PersonClubDao (or any other DAO) in **HomePage** class in wicket module and display some data from the database.

Here is the **HomePage** class:

```java
public class HomePage extends WebPage {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SpringBean
    private PersonClubDao personClubDao;

    public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);
        // TODO Add your page's components here
        //no code here so far
    }
}
```

and the wicket/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.microapp.hello.dao" />    

</beans>
```

If I try to make some dummy interface and dummy class and wire it using `@SpringBean`, it works just fine. But when I try to wire any of my DAOs, the application crashes. I'm not quite sure what to do, I tried to add dependecies for hibernate packages into my pom.xml, but without luck and googling also didn't help.

Here is the full stack trace:

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personClubDao': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:296)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:73)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:534)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:357)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:167)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:615)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308)
... 65 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is described in your the, see

**No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found** for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

That means you haven't configurated hibernate **SessionFactory**, google an example how to create SessionFactory using Spring, see

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html

If you use Hibernate it requires to create some other beans in the Spring context.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed! You just saved my life!