# @Autowired breaking the junit tests

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have implemented a DAO interface which was extending JpaRepository. In one of the implementation, I needed session so I used @Autowired annotation with the sessionFactory, which is breaking my unit tests. Unit tests are working if I don't put @Autowired with the sessionFactory but then the functionality will fail. 
Here is the code of my implementation with file names.

TagDAO.java

```
package dao;

//All the imports 

@Repository
public interface TagDAO extends JpaRepository<Tag, Integer> {

public List<Object[]> getTagsWithQuestionCount(Pageable pageable) throws SomeException;
public Long getTagCount() throws SomeException;

public Tag findByTagName(@Param("tagName") String tagName) throws SomeException;

public List<Object[]> getAllTagIdsAndNames() throws SomeException;
public Tag save(Tag tag);
}
```

TagDAOImpl.java

```
package dao.impl;

//All the imports 

public class TagDAOImpl implements TagDAO {


@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactory")
EntityManager entityManager;

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public Long getTagCount() throws RFPDatabaseException {

  //implementation
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public Tag findByTagName(String tagName) throws RFPDatabaseException {

  //implementation
}

@Override
public List<Object[]> getAllTagIdsAndNames() throws RFPDatabaseException {
//implementation
}

   @Override
public List<Object[]> getTagsWithQuestionCount(Pageable pageable) throws RFPDatabaseException {
   //implementation
    }
}

@Override
public Tag save(Tag tag) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(tag, NULL_TAG_MESSAGE);
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(tag);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return tag;

}
//Rest are todo because of the JpaRepository extends

@Override
public List<Tag> findAll(Sort sort) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<Tag> findAll(Iterable<Integer> ids) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
//........
// A bunch of other methods 
}
```

TagDAOImplTest.java

```
package dao.impl;
//All the imports 

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextHierarchy({ 
  @ContextConfiguration(classes = EntityManagerConfig.class),
  @ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
})

public class TagDAOImplTest {
@Mock(name = "entityManager")
private EntityManager entityManagerMock;

@Mock
private CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilderMock;

@Mock
private CriteriaQuery<Tag> criteriaQueryMock;

@Mock
private CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQueryMockForTagCount;

@Mock
private CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteriaQueryMockForGetAllTagIdsAndNames;

@Mock
private Root<Tag> rootTagMock;

@Mock
private Path<Object> pathMock;

@Mock
private Expression<Long> expression;

@Mock
private Predicate predicateMock;

@Mock
private TypedQuery<Tag> typedQueryMock;

@Mock
private TypedQuery<Long> typedQueryMockForTagCount;

@Mock
private TypedQuery<Object[]> typedQueryMockForGetAllTagIdsAndNames;

@InjectMocks
private TagDAOImpl tagDAOImpl;

@Mock
private Tag tag;

@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

/**
 * This method initialize objects for {@link TagDAO} class.
 */
@Before
public void setup() {
    tagDAOImpl = new TagDAOImpl();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    when(entityManagerMock.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(criteriaBuilderMock);

}
// All the unit tests
}
```

beans.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>
<bean id ="tagDAO" class ="dao.impl.TagDAOImpl"/>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<import resource="beans.xml" />
<import resource="spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml" />
```

Now, if I remove the @Autowired from my TagDAOImpl unit tests will fail and will give the following error

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.MergedContextConfiguration.getParentApplicationContext(MergedContextConfiguration.java:438)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tagDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory': No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 50 more
```

If I remove the @Autowired my functionality will fail. I have looked into a bunch of existing solution for similar kind of problem. Nothing is helping. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you configure hibernate Session Factory? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33965394/appfuse-wicket-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-org-hibernate-sessionfactory

Comment: I don't see where you're making your code scan the Bean.xml file

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure I understood the problem, but I noticed in "applicationContext.xml" you import "beans.xml". But you have "Bean.xml". Is that on purpose?

Comment: Bean was a typing error in the question, I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

> Unit tests are working if I don't put @Autowired with the
>   sessionFactory.

Do you get NPE without `@Autowired` annotation? I would expect that.

If you need to use `sessionFactory` in `TagDAOImpl` from your Spring Context then some type of dependency injection is obviously required. In tests you either mock your bean or use a real one, which I think is exactly what you try to do as I can't see any `@Mock` for `sessionFactory`.

So I noticed in `applicationContext.xml` **you import** `beans.xml`. But **you have** `Bean.xml`, which I think should be imported instead. Hopefully it will fix your problem. Let us know if that's not the case.

Comment: I have chaned the Bean to beans.xml in the question, that was just a bad typing error in the question, it is beans.xml in my project. That's not the problem.

Comment: If @Autowired is not there I don't get NPE and tests work fine. But, I need autowired annotation with the sessionFactory to make sure the functionality works. What kind of dependency injection is exactly required?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:**/applicationContext.xml",
                          })
```

on your Unit test class to load the applicationContext xml into test case so that the beans will be available o you.
This will create the dependency your class needs at runtime and thus you may not get NPE

Comment: have u tried this on your unit test class. right below @runWith ?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't fix.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    tagDAOImpl = new TagDAOImpl();
    ...
}
```

But then at the same time you have `@InjectMocks` at this field, which should init `tagDAOImpl` for you and inject provided mocks. In `setup` you essentially create a completely new instance of the `TagDAOImpl` without any beans injected. It can be the reason behind your problem. Try to remove initialization of this field in your `setup` method. It may help. And tell us if that's not the case. Either way, creation of another instance of this field seems redundant.